# Upload chunks of file Android

Tags: android

I've copied the following code from [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/multipart-http-requests), I'm trying to upload chunks of the file to monitor the progress, is it correct to flush the stream as shown in the code below and use it as a progress? the code i'm asking about is surrounded by stars

```
    public String multipartRequest(String urlTo, Map httpPara, String filepath, String filefield) throws ParseException, IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****"+Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())+"*****";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";

        String result = "";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

        String[] q = filepath.split("/");
        int idx = q.length - 1;

        try {
                File file = new File(filepath);
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                URL url = new URL(urlTo);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + filefield + "\"; filename=\"" + q[idx] +"\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + getMimeType(filepath) + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while(bytesRead > 0) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        ///////////***********************///////////// 
        **********      outputStream.flush(); *********  
        ///////////***********************/////////////
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);


                Iterator iter = httpPara.entrySet().iterator();

                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry para = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
                     outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                     outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + para.getKey().toString() + "\"" + lineEnd);
                     outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain"+lineEnd);
                     outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                     outputStream.writeBytes(para.getValue().toString());
                     outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                }
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                result = this.convertStreamToString(inputStream);

                fileInputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                return result;
        } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("MultipartRequest","Multipart Form Upload Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call `flush()` on DataOutputStream any time, there is no restrictions. It will automatically call `flush` on underlying connection, so your server should receive that chuck of data immediately, which you can use as progress update.

See [here for additional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#flush()) reference

`The flush method of DataOutputStream calls the flush method of its underlying output stream.`